# Prevent `IndexOf` from matching the full-width "？" looking for the half-width "?" when LC_ALL is "ja.UTF-8"

Tags: c#, docker

source code:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            Console.WriteLine("aaa？".IndexOf("?", 1 - 1) + 1);
            Console.WriteLine("aaa?".IndexOf("?", 1 - 1) + 1);
            Console.WriteLine("aaa?".IndexOf("？", 1 - 1) + 1);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1.10 AS base
RUN apt-get update \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y locales tzdata libc6-dev libgdiplus \
    && dpkg-reconfigure --frontend=noninteractive locales \
    && echo "Asia/Tokyo" > /etc/timezone \
    && rm -rf /etc/localtime \
    && dpkg-reconfigure --frontend=noninteractive tzdata \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
ENV LC_ALL ja.UTF-8

WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ConsoleApp1/ConsoleApp1.csproj", "ConsoleApp1/"]
RUN dotnet restore "ConsoleApp1/ConsoleApp1.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/ConsoleApp1"
RUN dotnet build "ConsoleApp1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ConsoleApp1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ConsoleApp1.dll"]
```

---

```
root@ip-172-31-43-240:/home/ubuntu/dotnet/ConsoleApp1# docker run goolsdu/test:v1
11/27/2020 23:27:23
Hello World!
0
4
0

root@ip-172-31-43-240:/home/ubuntu/dotnet/ConsoleApp1# docker run goolsdu/test:v2
2020/11/27 23:30:33
Hello World!
4
4
4
```

The need now is to turn the LC_TIME format of docker image into YYYY/MM/DD, but find "aaa? ". IndexOf ("?", 1 - 1) results incorrectly, and the half question mark does not have the string "aaa?" "In, but the result of execution is 4, how to solve it?" Please help me

Comment: when without ENV LC_ALL ja.UTF-8  then output 0,4,0

Comment: when with ENV LC_ALL ja.UTF-8 then output 4,4,4

Comment: I don't know why

Comment: the last paragraph of your question is confusing, could you please put it more clearly?

Answer (score 0):

By default `IndexOf` uses the current culture for its operations. Apparently full and half-width `?` are equivalent in the japanese culture on your system.

You can use an overload which allows you to pass a [`StringComparison`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparison) to avoid the culture dependence. Here either `StringComparison.Ordinal` or `StringComparison.InvariantCulture` would be appropriate.

```
"aaa？".IndexOf("?", 0, StringComparison.Ordinal)
```

---

I could not reproduce this problem on Windows using the `ja-JP` culture, so this behaviour appears to be specific to your operating system.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ja-JP");
"aaa？".IndexOf("?", 0, StringComparison.CurrentCulture) == -1
"aaa？".IndexOf("?", 0, StringComparison.Ordinal) == -1
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, because there's a lot of this use in the code, so my idea now is to change the LC_TIME inside Docker, but it hasn't worked

Answer (score 0):

I wanted the result to be like this, but I didn't know how to change DockerFile

```
root@ip-172-31-43-240:/home/ubuntu/dotnet/ConsoleApp1# docker run goolsdu/test:v2*
2020/11/27 23:27:23
Hello World!
0
4
0
```